# How to get search result from material-table and display it in PDF

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I have integrated material table in react (reference: https://material-table.com/).

I want to export the displayed data (all data and search results) to PDF using `jspdf`. Unable to get that in material table.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to get all the data as well as searched data.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you provide some code on how you pass the data etc?

Comment: <div id="temp-material-table" style={{ maxWidth: '100%' }}>     <MaterialTable title={tableTitle} columns={columns} data={tableData} icons={tableIcons} options={{
            exportButton: true,
            exportCsv: (columns, data) => {
              alert('You should develop a code to export ' + data.length + ' rows');
            }        }}
          actions={[  {
              icon: 'Export',
              tooltip: 'Export to pdf',
              isFreeAction: true,
              onClick: (event ,tdata) =>console.log("event data==>>  ",this.props.data)
            } ]} /> </div>

Comment: All the data is available in export to csv option. Similar way I am looking into getting the data when export to pdf.. Thanks

Comment: So you you can access the data in the csv option. What exactly is the problem than?

Comment: export to csv is for excel.. I want to do that for PDF.. exporting material table data to pdf.. in export csv data is available.. outside that function data all data and/or searched data is not available for exporting it to any other format

Comment: export const materialTableOptions: Options<any> = {
  exportButton: {
    csv: true,
    pdf: true
  }
};

Answer (score 0):

Try to `useRef()` from react.

```
import {useRef} from "react";

const YourComponent = () => {
    const tableRef = useRef();

    console.log(tableRef.current.dataManager.data); // check proper field

    return <MaterialTable tableRef={tableRef} {...restProps} />;
}
```